# Find elements in array list with certain properties

Tags: java

I have an arrayList with five objects where I now have to find all elements where the surname is Smith and have another class to print it. How do I do this? 
I have three classes: A student class, a class room and a Driver class containing an exam method. I have to make a method called:
withName(String name) in the class called "class room" and then have it printed by the exam mode. How do I do this?

Firstly I made a getName() method in the student class:

```
public String getName(){

    return name;
}
```

Then I tried with:

```
public Student withName(String name){

    for( Student s : students){
        if(s != null && m.getName().contains("Smith"))
            return s;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you mean java??

Comment: I assume you meant to use the `java` tag, not `javascript`

Comment: You seem to be mixing up two different exercises. What does `withInstrument` have to do with the question about `withName`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried following an example from earlier. I have edited the question now

Comment: What is `m` within `withName(...)`? You never define it in this scope, so the line `m.getName().contains(...)` will fail to compile with `cannot find symbol`. I assume the `m` is meant to be an `s`

Comment: Yes I just corrected it as I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

This an answer to your question,
but I'm not going to spoon feed you the solution.

1. [Read This API Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
2. Implement one of these: Comparator<Student>.
3. Use your Comparator to find matching students.

Comment: I have tried: public class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{ ... However, I don't quite understand how to get a person with surname Smith by comparing objects this way? Our teacher talked about using equals in class so I'm positive it's the right way to go. I simply can't see how

Comment: the @Marcel Jaques Machado solution seems like a good option instead of using a Comparator

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that:

```
    // find all elements where the surname is ...
    public List<Student> withName(String name) {
        List<Student> auxList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        for (Student s : students) {
            if (s != null && s.getName().contains("Smith"))
                auxList.add(s);
        }

        return auxList;
    }
```